# Magento Shopping cart heading displaying wrongly

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magneto, i have a problem in magento cart page where the details of the products displaying with their headings are wrong. Please give me a solution.

[See the heading its nowhere related to the product details, ie, its shuffling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdInG.png)

Check this link : http://thorsignia.net/khidmaa/index.php/checkout/cart

Comment: Looks like your <td> tags are misplaced. Can you update with the code snippet of that table. i think the id of the table is **shopping-cart-table**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple answer is...

Go to checkout/cart.phtml

And then after take your first th copy this `'<th rowspan="1">Remove</th>'`under the `<thead>` tag  and add it  after this last `'<th class="a-center" colspan="1">Subtotal</th>'` your problem is slove.

Answer (score 0):

You can update cart layout through

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your theme checkout/cart.phtml

```
 <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>  
 <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>

 <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>

 <th class="a-center cart-price-head" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">
    <span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></span>
 </th>

 <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center">
     <?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>
 </th>

 <th class="a-center cart-total-head" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">
   <?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?>
 </th>

 <th class="a-center" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>
```